# WPF. Help to bind combobox items

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have view model that has a list (not observable collection, i guess it's not important) of **classes** that are available to choose for a document (inventory, packing list, e.t.c) and a **document** with exact class instance assigned

```
        public class MyViewModel
        {
                public DocumentViewModel Document { get; set; }
                public IList<ClassViewModel> Classes { get; set; }
        }

       public class DocumentViewModel
       {
            public ClassViewModel Class { get; set; }
            ...
       }

    public class ClassViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

I have to show `combobox` that should display available document classes, and selected item should be a class of document of `MyViewModel` instance .

The following code doesn't work for me :

```
 <ComboBox 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Classes}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="Title" 
     SelectedValuePath="Title"
     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Document.Class, Mode=TwoWay}"
/>
```

What I do wrong here?

Comment: Code looks good, can you explain what exactly "The following code doesn't work for me :" means? Is nothign showing? The value gets not set? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Combobox items are shown but SelectedValue is not chosen from items and selected value is not synchronized when changed

Comment: p.s. Moreover, when i change item in combobox, combobox became surrounded with red border for some reason.

Comment: The red box is usually because of validation rules.

Try to give the ComboBox a x:Name and then bind SelectedValue to a TextBlock 
 `<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Classes}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectedValuePath="Title" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Document.Class, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}"/>`
Do you get anything in the TextBlock ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have changed my markup by removing

```
SelectedValuePath="Title"
```

Now everything is ok!